# Looking for pointers on calculating error bounds

Tags: error

I have a population P - P has a wide variety of measurable aspects A. One key aspect is V - the effect on my system. This is always measurable.

A subset of P self-reports a subset of the measurable aspects. "Very few" of P actually report in on all possible variables.

A standing question is: given that only partial information is available for P, what can be said about all of P, as opposed to just the sampling which self-reported.

Let's say some 1% of P report on aspect A1, with possible values x1...xN. This 1% also have measurable V. However, since this 1% of P behave this way, can we say *all* of P behaves this way? How confident can I be about this - to what number?

A few comments on the data-

- Most of the data is categorical; V is numeric; none of it is ranked.
- Most of the frequency distributions of data in a given aspect follows the power distribution.
- Comparing independent subsets of the population against each other appears to require the Kolmogorov-Smirnof test.
- The data is actually internal business data & therefore I have obscured it.

edit:

Each member of P chooses (out of my control) to respond or not per each aspect of A.  V is a different kind of aspect - also out of my control, but 100% measurable by me.

Imagine a sociological survey where people have the option to report on themselves, as well as having the option to leave questions blank. The V value is something measurable externally  - say, the survey is given to all people who are fined money for traffic violations; most people don't fill it out, most who do fill it out partially. V would be the cost of the violation(this is a *made-up example, not the actual data*).

Comment: How is the subset of P selected? Random?

Comment: @AndyW: No. P's subsets reporting self-select themselves to report.

Comment: It is very important to state clearly how the subsets are selected, and if/how it is related to V. Any reasonable answer will need this information, so I suggest you elaborate on this selection process in the question.

Comment: @AndyW: added the information per your request.